# flex container and ngIf center horizontally

Tags: angular, css, flexbox

I have a flex container and some elements that can be add or remove using ngIf.

I want another element always visible, center horizontally, there is also a fixed element at bottom something like:

[image]

in the blue part, I will have different elements depending on ngIf conditios:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column">

  <element1 fxFlex *ngIf="element === '1'">
  </element1>

  <element2 fxFlex *ngIf="element === '2'">
  </element2>

 <element3 fxFlex *ngIf="element === '3'">
  </element3>

  <!-- fixed element center -->

  <div class="center">
  </div>

   <!-- fixed element at bottom -->
   <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="30px">

  </div>
```

```
.center {   
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: can you please attach the fiddle link...use align-items: center;

Answer (score 0):

For elements you want to be visible all the time, apply :

> position:absolute

For orange element use

> bottom:0;

and for yellow

> use right:0,top:50%;

If you want more details please post a fiddle for the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering with the yellow element is that with your styling you are treating it as a flexbox parent/container element, whereas you actually want to treat it as a child element to its parent.

Adding the following to the parent div should centre the yellow box:

`<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">`

Another problem that you're going to encounter however is that as you programatically add in your additional elements, they will flow with the yellow div. Depending on what you want to achieve in terms of the layout, it might be that you need to reconsider the way you wanted to lay out the elements, although it's not clear from your post how you intend to lay these out when the additional elements are added to the page.